# I can't find my recently deleted answer

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

Before the weekend I posted an answer which was reasonably well received, with a bunch of upvotes.

It was deleted because, although it told an of interesting and relevant experience, it did not actually answer the question.

I have absolutely no problem with my answer being deleted.

However, there was a comment which stated that, if I updated it, it could possibly be re-opened.

I did. It wasn’t.

Obviously moderators are busy, and I am not sure how you would even notice my update.

For a few days, I could still see my deleted question and was thinking of posting a comment to the delete asking if I had updated sufficiently for reopening, but now I can no longer find and trace of my answer.

[This SE meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13193/how-do-i-find-questions-or-answers-that-ive-deleted/13203#13203) question has an answer that says

> Since June 2013, deleted questions and answers that were posted in the past 60 days, can be seen using the "deleted recent questions" and "deleted recent answers" links on the questions and answers tabs in your user profile.

Did that change? Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: To what question were you answering? Can you post a link?

Comment: @Noon I guess that's what he's trying to find out..

Comment: @Cashbee I was talking about a link to the question, not the answer ^^

Comment: @Noon well if he had that, he would probably find his answer ;)

Comment: Yup, you nailed it. I couldn't remember the question, and couldn't see any trace of it in my activity

Comment: Does [this link](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/4957) show you the deleted answer? (for anyone else wanting to use the same link, replace 4957 with your user number)

Comment: Indeed it does. Thanks for that helpful trick. Hmmm, since most users won't know it, why not just make deleted questions visible to the user, if not to others?

Comment: Deleted question *are* visible to the user and not others. That's why you can see your deleted answer even without the requisite rep. See my answer below for how to access your deleted answer list through the UI (without that link)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you mean your answer that was deleted two days ago here:

[How can I initiate a talk of money with my friend about his business idea?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/19248/how-can-i-initiate-a-talk-of-money-with-my-friend-about-his-business-idea/19258#19258)

It was deleted by a moderator so normal users can not vote to undelete it. You'll have to flag the answer for moderator intervention if you want it to be considered for undeletion. You should be able to see your own deleted answer by visiting the above link despite not having the 2000 reputation "see deleted posts" privilege.

Comment: Yup, that's it, thanks! It is annoying that I can't see my deleted answer if I can't remember the question, though. I am used to just looking at my activity. Guess I will just have to earn some rep on this site :-)  Thanks very much for helping.

Comment: @Mawg Did you check your inbox? I think you should still have AJ's comment notification since it was left within an hour of deleting, so you should be able to get to the post from there ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231668/how-do-notifications-on-deleted-posts-work), but I can't easily check this myself). And thanks for editing,  please do flag if you feel it's ready and we'll check it out ASAP :)

Comment: Thanks, I flagged it

Answer (score 7):

Here is how you can view your recently deleted answers:

[image: view recently deleted]

If this looks like too much work for you, you can go to this link (replacing 4957 with your user number): https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/4957

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful to know. I can't figure how I overlooked it.